# Angular 1 - Service to detect change redux state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angularjs-injector

I am trying to create a service that will detect a change in the redux state of my application to be able to redirect to different pages.

The error that I am getting is:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: translate2FilterProvider <- 
translate2Filter
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unprp0=translate2FilterProvider%20%3C-%20translate2Filter

Here is my redirection service:

```
import * as angular from 'angular'
import {
    IStateService,
} from 'angular-ui-router'
import {subscribe} from 'awesomeLibrary_web_stateSubscribe'
import {getUser} from '../redux/get'
import {
    INgRedux,
    State,
} from '../redux/redux'
import {RouterParams} from '../redux/root/router/routerReducers'


export class RedirectionService {

    constructor(
        public  $ngRedux:       INgRedux,
        public  $stateParams:   RouterParams,
        public  $state:         IStateService,
        $scope:                 angular.IScope,
    ) {

        $scope.$on('$destroy', this.$ngRedux.connect(s => this._mapState(s))(this))

        $ngRedux.subscribe(async () => { await this.redirectinDetection() })

    }

    public async redirectinDetection() {

        const state = this.$ngRedux.getState()
        const user = getUser(state)

        if (this.$state.is('site.user')) {
            // Here it will redirect to user/:userId
            if (user && !this.$stateParams.userId) {
                this.$state.go('site.user', {userId: user.id})
            }
            else if (!user) {
                // not logged in
            }
        }

    }

    private _mapState = (state: State) => ({
        user: getUser(state),
    })

}

angular.module('Site')
    .service('redirectionSerivce', RedirectionService)
```

Below is the component in which I am trying to inject the redirectionService into. It is the main top level component as I want this service to run on the entire site:

```
import * as es6Promise from 'es6-promise'
es6Promise.polyfill()

import * as angular from 'angular'
import 'angular-animate'
import 'angular-aria'
import 'angular-local-storage'
import 'angular-material'
import 'angular-messages'
import 'angular-ui-router'
import 'ng-redux'
import {
    INgRedux,
    State,
} from './redux/redux'
import {RouterParams} from './redux/root/router/routerReducers'
import '../../node_modules/angular-elastic/elastic'
import '../../node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.css'
import './cUser/cUser'
import './mConfig/persistentQueryParamsConfig'
import './mConfig/routeConfig'
import './mDirectives/mDirectives'
import './mServices/mServices'
import './redux/redux'

class SiteController {

    constructor(
        $ngRedux: INgRedux,
    ) {
        $ngRedux.connect(s => this._mapState(s))(this)
    }

    private _mapState = (state: State) => ({
        metaTitle:          'title'),
    })

}

class StatelessController {

    constructor(
        public $stateParams: RouterParams,
    ) {}

}

angular.module('Site').controller('SiteController', SiteController)
angular.module('Site').controller('StatelessController', StatelessController)
angular.module('Site').run([
    'redirectionService',
    angular.noop, // tslint:disable-line:no-unbound-method
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to inject a service (possibly out of these two parts of code you've included) called translate2Filter which is not being found

Check your html for a filter called like that, or look on all project to find where this filter is called.

Regards

Pablo García